# Finding RSS Feed

Tags: rss

How can I find if a given page has RSS Feed available as browsers (FF) show RSS icon in address bar if the page has an RSS feed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look into the source of this very page. You will find the following `<link>`:

```
   <link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" 
    title="Feed for question 'Finding RSS Feed'" href="/feeds/question/2022542">
```

You should be able to parse any HTML page with a DOM parser, and look for `alternate` links of the correct type.